# mathematica crashes on startup

Tags: macos, crash, installation, wolfram-mathematica

I installed Mathematica 8.0.4 on a Mac 10.8.2 server. The licensing portion went ok, but the application crashes during start up.

Here is a bit from the error log:

```
Process:         Mathematica [8730]
Path:            /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/Mathematica
Identifier:      com.wolfram.Mathematica
Version:         8.0.4.3539075 (8.0)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [592]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2012-10-27 13:08:32.722 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C60)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          882070 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           12
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  210 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   12
Anonymous UUID:                      93B2B8EE-4FF6-599A-4DBF-859A4BF3882A

Crashed Thread:  1  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
```

Here is what didn't work:

- Removing and reinstalling Mathematica
- Removing the user folder (in /Users//Library/Mathematica)
- Resetting Mathematica with alt+enter when starting it

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Suggest you contact Wolfram Tech Support.

Comment: Can you show us the output of 'ulimit -a'? Maybe try increasing your stack size limit with 'ulimit -s unlimited'.